# when do printf() and scanf() functions are linked statically or dynamically to application?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, static-linking, c-standard-library

When a C program is compiled it under goes in the order of pre-processor,compiler,assembler,linker.
One of the main tasks for `linker` is to make code of library functions available to your program.
Linker can link them in two ways static or dynamically..

`stdio.h` contains only declarations,no definitions are  present in it.
we only include `stdio.h` in program to say compiler about the return type and name of functions `eg(printf(),scanf(),getc(),putc()...)..`
Then how `printf()` and `scanf()` are linked in the example program below?

- **If it is linking dynamically which "DLL" is responsible in linking??**
- **Is total "C" Library is linked dynamically to program??**

```
    #include "stdio.h"
 
    int main()
    {
      int n;
 
       printf("Enter an integer\n");
       scanf("%d", &n);
 
       if (n%2 == 0)
           printf("Even\n");
       else
           printf("Odd\n");
 
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Same way as you link C runtime (standard library)

Comment: Your c program has a lot of things which you should avoid them in future. 1) **int main(){}** should be **int main(void){}**. 2) You should check **scanf()** for errors. 3) Why, I repead why do you need **\n** in here =>> **printf("Enter an integer\n");** ? 4) Is there any reason for you to not use **brackets** in if-else ?

Comment: @Michi 1) the correct signature is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, 4) Adding brackets around a single line of code in an `if` statement just wastes vertical space and clutters up the code. It's just a style issue and people are free to do it either way (but the indentation does need to be fixed no matter which style you prefer).

Comment: @CareyGregory And if there is no arguments ? The Standard says **int main(void){}** or **int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}**. Why only **int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}** please explain.

Comment: @CareyGregory About brackets, I was intended to know OPs answer, but if you insist then let me tell you that, just because there are optional things in c language it doesn't mean that you shouldn't use them. I know that in that peace of code is no problem by ignoring them, but at some point it will be. I think that people when they share their code should have more respect for that, but this is my personal opinion.

Comment: @Michi I stand corrected on `main(void)` being acceptable in the standard. However, adding braces around single lines of code isn't necessary, it adds clutter, and it causes no harm whatsoever as long as the future programmers who maintain it know what they're doing.

Comment: @CareyGregory I didn't said that he should use brackets in that code, what I was asking was: **4) Is there any reason for you to not use brackets in if-else ?** Was more a curiosity and nothing more.

Comment: @Michi You said he should avoid doing the things on your list.

Comment: @Michi I don't understand why you think you *don't* want a `\n` on the first call to `printf`.  Without it the prompt may not be visible to the user.

Comment: @zwol there are a lot of ways to avoid that like =>> printf("Enter an integer:>  "); or printf("Enter an integer\t");, but I will not going to argue with you about that :):

Comment: There are no DLLs, static linling, or dynamic linking in the C language. If you are interested in a particular implementation which may have these things, ask about that specific implementation.

Answer (score 19):

I think the question you are trying to ask is: “I know that functions like `printf` and `scanf` are implemented by the C runtime library.  But I can use them without telling my compiler and/or IDE to link my program with the C runtime library.  Why don’t I need to do that?”

The answer to that question is: “Programs that *don’t* need to be linked with the C runtime library are very, very rare.  Even if you don’t explicitly use any library functions, you will still need the startup code, and the compiler might issue calls to `memcpy`, floating-point emulation functions, and so on ‘under the hood.’ Therefore, as a convenience, the compiler automatically links your program with the C runtime library, unless you tell it to *not* do that.”

You will have to consult the documentation for your compiler to learn how to tell it not to link in the C runtime library.  GCC uses the `-nostdlib` command-line option.  Below, I demonstrate the hoops you have to jump through to make that work...

```
$ cat > test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { puts("hello world"); return 0; }
^D
$ gcc -nostdlib test.c && { ./a.out; echo $?; } 
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start
/tmp/cc8svIx5.o: In function ‘main’:
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to ‘puts’
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`puts` is obviously in the C library, but so is this mysterious "entry symbol `_start`".  Turn off the C library and you have to provide *that* yourself, too...

```
$ cat > test.c
int _start(void) { return 0; }
^D
$ gcc -nostdlib test.c && { ./a.out; echo $?; }
Segmentation fault
139
```

It links now, but we get a segmentation fault, because `_start` has nowhere to return to!  The operating system expects it to call `_exit`.  OK, let's do that...

```
$ cat > test.c
extern void _exit(int);
void _start(void) { _exit(0); }
^D
$ gcc -nostdlib test.c && { ./a.out; echo $?; }
/tmp/ccuDrMQ9.o: In function `_start':
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

... nuts, `_exit` is a function in the C runtime library, too!  Raw system call time...

```
$ cat > test.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
void _start(void) { syscall(SYS_exit, 0); }
^D
$ gcc -nostdlib test.c && { ./a.out; echo $?; }
/tmp/cchtZnbP.o: In function `_start':
test.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `syscall'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

... nope, `syscall` is *also* a function in the C runtime.  I guess we just have to use assembly!

```
$ cat > test.S
#include <sys/syscall.h>
.text
.globl _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
        movq $SYS_exit, %rax
        movq $0, %rdi
        syscall
$ gcc -nostdlib test.S && { ./a.out; echo $?; }
0
```

And that, finally, works.  On my computer.  It wouldn't work on a different operating system, with a different assembly-level convention for system calls.

You might now be wondering what the heck `-nostdlib` is even good for, if you have to drop down to assembly language just to make system calls.  It's intended to be used when compiling completely self-contained, low-level system programs like the bootloader, the kernel, and (parts of) the C runtime itself — things that were going to have to implement their own everything *anyway*.

If we had it to do all over again from scratch, it might well make sense to separate out a low-level language-independent runtime, with *just* the syscall wrappers, language-independent process startup code, and the functions that *any* language's compiler might need to call "under the hood" (`memcpy`, `_Unwind_RaiseException`, `__muldi3`, that sort of thing).  The problem with that idea is it rapidly suffers mission creep — do you include  `errno`?  Generic threading primitives?  (Which ones, with which semantics?)  The dynamic linker? An implementation of `malloc`, which several of the above things need?  Windows's `ntdll.dll` began as this concept, and it's 1.8MB on disk in Windows 10, which is (slightly) *bigger* than `libc.so` + `ld.so` on my Linux partition.  And it's rare and difficult to write a program that *only* uses `ntdll.dll`, even if you're Microsoft (the only example I'm *sure* of is `csrss.exe`, which might as well be a kernel component).

Answer (score 5):

Generally, standard C libraries are linked dynamically. This is mainly because of the reasons that once a program has been statically linked, the code in it is fixed forever. If someone finds and fixes a bug in `printf` or `scanf`, then every program has to be linked again in order to pick up the fixed code.

In case of dynamic linking, none of the executable files (created after linking) contains a copy of the code for `printf` or `scanf`. If a new, fixed, version of `printf` is available, then it is picked up at run time.

Comment: Thanks for reply..If it is linking dynamically which "DLL" is responsible in linking?? and Is total "C" Library is linked dynamically to program??

Comment: @LearNer; *.If it is linking dynamically which "DLL" is responsible in linking??*: I have no idea about that. * Is total "C" Library is linked dynamically to program??* : I said *generally*. I can't say it with surety. A C compiler writer/developer can explain these in much detail. I just gave you a rough idea.

Comment: If an implementation bundles and statically links functions like `printf`, `scanf`, etc. then it can let programmers select from different versions of the function which are maximally suitable for their particular use cases.  While it might be nice to be able to fix some C runtime bugs or quirks, having corner-case behaviors change spontaneously is often not a good thing.

Comment: I think the main reason for dynamic linking is that you don't want the code for those functions replicated a million times on disk and a thousand times in memory. The standard library exists *once* (OK, perhaps once *per version*), on disk and in RAM repectively.

Answer (score 4):

```
-static-libstdc++
```

> When the g++ program is used to link a C++ program, it normally
>   automatically links against libstdc++. If libstdc++ is available as a
>   shared library, and the -static option is not used, then this links
>   against the shared version of libstdc++. That is normally fine.
>   However, it is sometimes useful to freeze the version of libstdc++
>   used by the program without going all the way to a fully static link.
>   The -static-libstdc++ option directs the g++ driver to link libstdc++
>   statically, without necessarily linking other libraries statically.

For more details, please check this thread. 
[How can i statically link standard library to my c++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103966/how-can-i-statically-link-standard-library-to-my-c-program)

Comment: It worth mentioning that this answer describes linking of GNU C++ Standard Library for GNU GCC compiler, which are popular major compiler and C++ standard library, but not unique ones. Also it has nothing to do with C library where `printf()` and `scanf()` are defined.

Answer (score -3):

They are linked statically, that way your program will be able to determine if there are any compilation errors before preceding to run the program.

Comment: False. It depends on compiler/linker settings. Also linking happens after compilation and cannot possibly influence compilation.