# How does gcc resolve malloc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

Since I started to learn c and c++, it has always confused me about some special functions such as "printf", "malloc","free","fork","new" and the standard iostream "cout" and "cin",whenever I try to go to definition of these members, it ends up with nothing or a simple declaration, I could never find the definition of them.Recently I'm learning compliers and the process of linking and it still seems unclear for these things.
suppose a simple *a.c*

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

the function "malloc" was declared in "stdlib.h" but with has not defined.
now I use gcc to compile it:

```
gcc -Wall a.c -o out;
```

However, this command execute successfully,
so I am wondering since there is no link options, how does it resolve the "malloc" function?
And I know it was implemented through OS-specified system call, but how does the call-tree looks like? I don't care much about the algorithm it uses, because it's too complicated for me, but I want to have a general idea of how these c standard library function works, Thanks!

Comment: gcc adds the *standard C runtime* library to the link by default. That's where the definition of malloc is found. Other  compilers will vary.

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. The code you show isn't valid C++. Please only tag the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: @john where can I find the run-time library and the source code for it？

Comment: The source code for GCC is available online.  Therein you can read the implementation of those functions.

Comment: Also please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). For example when it comes to the size of types, unless you use the fixed-size integers (like `int32_t`) they don't have a fixed specified size. The size of `int` may be different from `4`. Always use `sizeof` to get the actual size, like in `int *a = malloc(isizeof *a);`.

Comment: As for your problem, I'm not even sure what the problem is. As long as you link with the standard C library (which is conveniently called `c`) you can access all standard C functions. You don't really need to know the definitions or have the source for them.

Comment: Pick one, either "C" or "C++" they are two different languages. In C++ you will be hard pressed to even find a reference to malloc/free (and even new/delete are no longer recommended there).

Comment: @ Some programmer dude Yes,it is. I use 4 just to mention that in my computer the Integer is 4 bytes

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer I think c and c++ are similar, you can use c library functions in c++, malloc is allowed in c++

Comment: `malloc()` is part of libc, not gcc. For GNU libc malloc() is implemented in `glibc/malloc/malloc.c`

Comment: libc.so and libstdc++.so are two different libraries.

Comment: @UsedToLove not the source code for GCC - more like the source code for glibc

Comment: @UsedToLove No C++ can use "C" libraries, mostly for backward compatibility. The philosophies behind them are totally different. C++ has classes/templates/concepts, can model things like pointer ownership (std::make_unique), you will learn about RAII and excpetion safe programming. So no modern C++ is nothing like "C".

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422487/when-do-printf-and-scanf-functions-are-linked-statically-or-dynamically-to-a/33422836#33422836 (not dupehammering because it's my answer)

Comment: @zwol I think this question here is mostly just asking where to find the source of the standard lib functions rather than how they are linked.

Comment: Thanks for your replys! I will read the referenced link one by one.