# Compile a static library link with standard library (static)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, static-libraries, standard-library

I'm trying to compile a static library (let's call it library.a). This library consumes resources of standard libraries. There is some way that the library can statically link a standard library.

I have proven something like:

```
g++ -c library -static-libstdc++ -o library.o
ar rcs library.o library.a
```

But if I do so there is no link to the standard libraries.

Then I have proved this way:

```
g++ library -static-stdlib -o library.o
ar rcs library.o library.a
```

But ask me to add a main function.

Is there any possibility of creating a static library by statically linking also standard libraries (std :: string, std :: vector, std :: cin, etc ...).

Thanks :)

Comment: Standard libraries are linked by default as far as I know.

Comment: Altough, If you want to statically link to it instead of dynamically, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26103966/2104697

Comment: The problem is that I am doing a wrapper of a code in C++ to be able to use it in C, in C I can not use the standard C++ libraries. The only way is to include inside the library the functions that I use from the standard library.

I do not have a program. To compile the code I should make a program and remove the g++ parameter "-c", but if I do this I have to put the main function in the code. And then I can not use it as a library.

Comment: Is the source you are compiling called library or library.c.  You should specify the filename with the extension.

Answer (score 22):

> Is there any possibility of creating a static library by statically linking also standard libraries

No, because you cannot link anything to a static library. You can link things only into
a file that is produced by the linker. Otherwise no linking is involved in its production.

The linker can produce two kinds of files: programs and shared libraries. 
Programs and shared libraries are similar: they're both composed of executable code
that the program loader can load into a process. They are *not* similar to a static
library. A static library is produced by the archiving program `ar`  and is just a
bag of object files - an archive - from which the linker can extract the ones it
needs to complete the linkage of a program or shared library.

A command like:

```
g++ -c library.cpp -static-libstdc++ -o library.o
```

just compiles `library.cpp` into `library.o` and ignores the linkage option `-static-libstdc++`
because `-c` means *Just compile. Don't link*

Your real problem only comes to light in one of your later comments<sup>1</sup>:

> The problem is that I am doing a wrapper of a code in C++ to be able to use it in C, 
>   in C I can not use the standard C++ libraries. The only way is to include inside 
>   the library the functions that I use from the standard library.

Now since a *shared* library is something that the linker can produce, you can statically
link `libstdc++` into a shared library. So, instead of making your C wrapper library
a static library, you could make it a shared libary.

It seems you already know how to wrap C++ code in a C API. So let's write such
a C wrapper that reverses the first N characters from an input buffer to an output buffer,
using the standard C++ library to do all the work:

**reverse.h**

```
#ifndef REVERSE_H
#define REVERSE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void reverse(char const * in, char * out, unsigned len);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

**reverse.cpp**

```
#include "reverse.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

extern "C" {

void reverse(char const * in, char * out, unsigned len)
{
    std::string s{in,len};
    std::reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
    std::copy(s.begin(),s.end(),out);
}

} // extern "C"
```

Then a C program that calls `reverse`:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <reverse.h>

int main()
{
    char in[] = "dlrow olleH";
    reverse(in,in,sizeof(in) - 1);
    puts(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Now we'll build our shared wrapper library.

Compile our one library source file:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c reverse.cpp
```

Notice `-fPIC`. All object files that we're going to link in a shared library
must be Position Independent Code. And as we're compiling one source file -
`-c reverse.cpp` - we can skip the `-o` option and accept the default, `-o reverse.o`

Then link our shared library:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libreverse.so reverse.o -static-libstdc++
```

Now the shared library is `./libreverse.so` and it has no runtime dependency
on `libstdc++`:

```
$ ldd libreverse.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca98c9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa178862000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa178498000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d17658c000)
```

Next compile our C program source file:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I. -c main.c
```

And finally link the program with `libreverse`:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lreverse
```

This program `./prog` has a runtime dependency on the shared library `libreverse.so`.
You can't statically link with `libreverse.so` because it's not a static library.
But `libreverse.so` *has* been statically linked with `libstdc++.a`, and has
a C API.

If `libreverse.so` was a serious library what we'd do now is is install it 
one of the runtime loader's standard
search directories, so that programs could load it automatically at runtime. We
could do that like:

```
$ sudo cp libreverse.so /usr/local/lib/
$ sudo ldconfig
```

But since `libreverse.so` is just a toy library we won't modify our system for
it.  Instead we'll just run `./prog` like:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. # For now, tell the loader to look for libraries here
$ ./prog
Hello world
```

So you can make a wrapper library with a C API and C++ internals, with `libstdc++`
statically linked, by making the wrapper library a *shared* library.

**But why bother?**

It seems that you want to bother because you believe that "in C I can not use the standard C++ libraries".

That is a misconception. Here's how you can build the same program with a *static*
wrapper library

First make your static wrapper library

```
$ rm libreverse.so  # Better delete the old shared one just to avoid confusion.
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -c reverse.cpp 
$ ar rcs libreverse.a reverse.o
```

Then compile your C source:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -I. -c main.c
```

At this point, you have an object file `main.o`, a static library `libreverse.a`
that contains (only) `reverse.o`, and to make `prog` you simply need to link `main.o`
and `libreverse.a(reverse.o)` together with the standard C library and the standard C++
library. There is no question of *C not allowing you to do this*. You finished
with C when you compiled `main.c`. These object files and libraries will be 
linked by your system linker, which will not know or care what language any of
them were compiled from.

So you could invoke the linker via `g++`, like:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lreverse
```

and once more you have a program that does this:

```
$ ./prog
Hello world
```

Or you could invoke the linker via `gcc`, like:

```
$ gcc -o prog main.o -L. -lreverse -lstdc++
```

which is just the same linkage, with just the same result:

```
$ ./prog
Hello world
```

As you see, the one difference between linking via `g++` rather than `gcc` is that
`g++` automatically adds both the standard C library and the standard C++ library
to the linker's inputs, and `gcc` doesn't add the C++ library, so you have to
do it yourself.

For that matter, if you happened to have GNU Fortran installed on your computer
you could do the same linkage with it:

```
$ $ gfortran -o prog main.o -L. -lreverse -lstdc++
$ ./prog
Hello world
```

although nothing in `prog` was written in Fortran.

C doesn't stop you from linking `libstdc++` with anything. A possible,
but unlikely, rational motive you might have for wishing to statically 
link `libstdc++` into a *library* with a C API is that you want somebody else to 
be able to link programs with this library on a system that doesn't have `libstdc++` or doesn't
have one that is [ABI compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) with yours. If that is your motivation, then 
make your library a shared one as shown above. Otherwise, just link `libstdc++`
with any program that depends on it.

---

[1] On Stackoverflow, always state your *real* problem *in your question*.
See [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)