# compile C++ application for old Linux environment

Tags: c++, spidermonkey

I've C++ application which runs on CentOS Linux 6.6, this machine contains two GCC with versions 4.4.7 and 4.9.3.

I started to use Mozilla SpiderMonkey JS engine 60, in which I need to convert some of my `std::string` to `std::u16string`, I used the way they provide in their examples:

```
static inline std::u16string StringtoU16(const std::string &str) {
    std::u16string wstr = u"";
    char16_t c16str[3] = u"\0";
    mbstate_t mbs;
    for (const auto& it : str) {
        memset(&mbs, 0, sizeof (mbs)); //set shift state to the initial state
        memmove(c16str, u"\0\0\0", 3);
        mbrtoc16(c16str, &it, 3, &mbs);
        wstr.append(std::u16string(c16str));
    }//for
    return wstr;
}
```

However, when I started to build the application on the previously mentioned environment, I found that the `<uchar.h>` is not found.

But when I built it on my PC using GCC 6.3.0, the code works fine.

I searched for other methods to do the conversion [Convert between string, u16string & u32string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/convert-between-string-u16string-u32string) but also It worked fine on my machine but on the application machine I got `<codecvt>` is not found.

I tried to take the output of building the application on my PC (GCC 6.3.0) and run it on the application machine (CentOS 6.6) using the following procedure:

1. Copied the libstdc++.so.6.0.22 to CentOS machine
2. Updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. Started the application

But I got that libstdc++ needs libc.so.6. I stopped here because when I copied it, it needs another library.

So, what is the Solution? Is there any way to compile on my PC and run on the app machine?

Comment: I know this is very controversial, but you could try static linking the relevant libraries into your build.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103966/how-can-i-statically-link-standard-library-to-my-c-program) SO question about static linking: "_You have a single file that can be copied to any machine with a compatible architecture and operating system and it will just work, no matter what version of what library is installed._"

Answer (score 4):

The old GCC versions on your CentOS machine do not support the C++11 features you're trying to use.

The solution I would recommend is to install the `devtoolset-8-gcc-c++` package from the Developer Toolset in Software Collections (see https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/ for instructions on setting that up -- the process is the same for `devtoolset-8-gcc` as for `devtoolset-7-gcc`).

That will install a newer GCC that can be used to compile C++11 code on the CentOS machine, producing binaries which will run on the old CentOS system without requiring any new runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (if [Jonathan one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56934629/841108)'s don't work) is to learn how to **build [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)** (Gnu Compiler Collection) -i.e. several compilers- and **[install](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) it from its source code**.

---

> I've got some C++ application which runs on CentOS Linux 6.6, this machine contains two GCC with versions 4.4.7 and 4.9.3.

Notice that both GCC 4.4 and [4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/) are **obsolete** and unmaintained by the FSF.

---

First, a successful build of GCC from its source code takes quite a lot of time (and a few gigabytes of disk space). Perhaps a few hours of (mostly CPU) time on a quite powerful PC (you may need at least 32 gigabytes of RAM, because a straight (non [cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler))  GCC compiler is [bootstrapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) and uses [LTO](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization)).

There are pro and cons to this approach. The pro is immediate: once you have learned how to compile GCC from its source code, you could get the latest [release](https://gcc.gnu.org/) ([GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) in july 2019) as soon as it is published, and that release is likely to support most of the latest [C++ language standards](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) (and several new ones, like Go or D) and increasingly fancy [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) targeting recent processors (maybe dynamically your current one). The cons includes learning the [configuration](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) procedure (quite a complex one, since GCC has many tunable features, bells and whistles) and of course waiting several hours for the build to complete.

So you need to make a trade-off. Are you willing to spend a few hours in learning how to build GCC, or not.

The configuration of an installed GCC is obtained with `gcc -v`  (or `gcc-8 -v` if your GCC was configured installed as `gcc-8` ....) and could *inspire* the configuration of a newly downloaded GCC.