# Running c++ in Windows as .exe

Tags: c++

I wrote a c++ program and converted it to a .exe file with the hopes to let it run on windows without needing to install a compiler. I ran well on my main computer (which has a compiler so it ran as expected) but did not run on another device. The error message shown was "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was not found"

How can I run a c++ program (or .exe file) from a flashdrive or other medium on any windows machine without extra installation.

Comment: Maybe you need the correct linkage when compiling. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing. Maybe: g++ my.cpp -o my.exe -static-libgcc

Comment: You need to ship your compilers runtime libraries along with your executable. Or statically link it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The program can't start because libgcc\_s\_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ programs require additional c++ standard and runtime libraries to run. Most linker links to these libraries dynamically. That is some dll are required for running the program. You can run the program from a portable flash drive by copying those dll to the same folder as the application.

Alternatively, some linkers also have option to statically link, that is incorporate the code in dll ( kind of ) to your binary exe.

So you can either find out what all dll is required and copy them to your local folder ( maybe use something like dependancy walker or [this newer one](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), i haven't actually used the newer alternative). Or use static linking like shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26107550/6459731) answer.