# How to compile a c++ program without library dependency?

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++. I am trying to compile a C++ program which requires some library such as libcurl.a and libcjose.so.0. The compilation is successful and I can run the program in my machine which has those libraries installed.

But when I tried to copy the binary **only** to another machine, it complains I am missing those libraries:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcjose.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Just wonder is there a way for my to copy/compile the binary only without install those libraries in another machine again?

Comment: You need to tell the linker where to look for those libraries.For gcc use `-l` flag and path to directory where these libraries are found.

Comment: Try to use *static* linking? Please use your favorite search engine to research the subject.

Comment: You need to understand : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries

Comment: https://helloacm.com/how-to-link-static-library-in-cc-using-gcc-compiler/

Answer (score 2):

**You can link all the library statically in your executable**. This procedure increase the executable size but let you the possibility to don't have installed libraries.

Further read in :

- [static and dynamic library](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/)
- [How to link static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103966/how-can-i-statically-link-standard-library-to-my-c-program)
- [Difference between static and dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the binary with shared libraries (.so, .dll), but it doesn't work very well if you try on another distribution. (ex: builded on Ubuntu, and you try on Fedora).