# How to include all dll in all exe file using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dependency-management, berkeley-db

I want to use BerkeleyDB in my project, but I plan to distribute the final program as an .exe file. How can I compile a program by adding both BerkeleyDB dlls to it so that I end up with a single executable that runs on machines that don't have those dlls?

P.S. I have read all similar questions, `Properties -> C++ -> Runtime Library -> /MT` and `Properties -> Use MFC in a static library` don`t work.

Comment: just use static libraries instead of dlls?

Comment: Why don't you just use an installer? Or is it important that the exe runs "out of the box"?

Comment: @PMF Yes, it`s important, I`m writing a program that I plan to distribute as an exe file.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am beginner in this, I already read [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170), but it didn`t help me in this case

Comment: I found a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844887/how-to-include-all-dlls-in-exe) similar to yours, I suggest you read it carefully.